# python Extract element from requests response

Tags: python, json, dictionary

i received this from an http request:

```
{u'accountDirectDialId': u'...', u'number': u'...', u'messageType': u'simple_message', u'configData': {u'audios': {u'message_audio': {u'duration': None, u'hashFile': u'...', u'id': u'16990559-acb9-11ea-af69-522c847d095a', u'name': None, u'uri': u'https://...'}}}, u'inboundCallerId': u'...', u'maxDestinationRetry': 1, u'hasVoicemail': False, u'voIp': {u'codePhone': 00}, u'hasMessage': True}
```

This is stored in a var.

Then if i do this, this works perfectly:

```
myvar["configData"]["audios"]["message_audio"]
```

But if i go one step further:

```
myvar["configData"]["audios"]["message_audio"]["uri"]
```

This fails miserably!
Why does this happen? uri is simply a parameter in "message_audio"
 when i do this:

```
print('Audio URI: "%s"\n' % type(myvar["configData"]["audios"]) )
```

I'm getting

```
Python Error by calling script "mass": <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
Message: string indices must be integers, not str
Exception: None

Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Output should be

```
'https://...'
```

Can anyone help?

UPDATE:

printing:

One level above:
    print('[%s]: Audio URI: "%s"\n' % (session_sip_call_id, type(CData.get("configData",None).get("audios",None).get("message_audio",None)) ) )

Prints:
    Audio URI: ""

But:
    print('[%s]: Audio URI: "%s"\n' % (session_sip_call_id, type(CData.get("configData",None).get("audios",None).get("message_audio",None).get("uri",None)) ) )

returns:

```
Audio URI: "<type 'unicode'>"
```

thanks!

Comment: the json you posted doesn't contain "audios"

Comment: This works for me - I got `https://...` as a result - what error or output do you get?

Comment: @komatiraju032 is correct

Comment: It works for me as well, what happens if you try `print(type(myvar["configData"]["audios"]["message_audio"]))` or print(myvar["configData"]["audios"]["message_audio"] .keys())` ?

Comment: what you expecting as output ? "This fails miserably! Why does this happen?" what hapend and what fails miserably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Python do you use?

In Python 2, Unicode needed to be converted
But in Python 3, this is done automatically, however you can use the following code snippet:

```
uni_var = str(myvar["configData"]["audios"]["message_audio"]["uri"])

print(uni_var)
```